# Autolayout image stretched when set the vertical spaces iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout

Hierarchy of views:

1. UIImageView cropped circular:

Constraints: Width, Height, Top Layout Guide vertical space, Align X to SuperView, Align X to Camera Button

2. Camera Button:

Constraints:Width, Height, Top space ImageView,Align center X to ImageView.

Trying this crops the image like this
[image]

Please advice to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints should be like :

ImageView : `horizontally in container, Vertically in container, fixed width, fixed height`

Button : `horizontally in container(align center x) and top`. If required then `fixed height and width` (this only need when button is not default means custom button other wise two constraints is enough - horizontal in container and top)

Then in your viewDidload set cornerradius of your imageview something like,

```
   self.imageViewProfile.layer.cornerRadius = 26.5; //corner radius should be exact half of your imageView's height
   self.imageViewProfile.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Hope this will help :)